# How will I get direct message into my webhook url

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I need to get all messages received in a account real time. 
I have registered my web-hook URL.
Also enabled a login with twitter button,by that I will get access_token of that user.

How will I get message when the user gets a message?

Comment: This question is a little unclear, at least to me. Can you try to rephrase what you have set up and what event you want to listen for?

Comment: I have created a twitter app. Also registered a webhook url.
In my app, I have enabled a twitter login and able to receive access token of all users who logged in with twitter. What I need is direct messages of all users logged in. I have their twitter access token.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/guides/direct-message-migration